# Button with glyp and label

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have a button with a glyp and a label (Play). See sample screenshot:

[image: Sample circle button]

If i tap the button the background color changes by the os and indicates a pressed state. Additionally i add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the label to the same event as the button. If the user tap the label the event is fired. So far so good.
The question is, how can i bind the label and the button so that the button indicates pressed state if i tap the label?

Comment: use ImageButton with binding source images and change image source with command action.

Comment: To change the pressed state, try to achieve this feature on each platform. Create a custom `Button` and add a bool property such as **IsChecked**. Then override the **OnElementPropertyChanged** in the custom renderer class, detect the value of the bool property to change the pressed state. For example: `protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    var customButton = Element as CustomButton;
    if (customButton.IsCheckeded)
    {
        Control.Pressed = true;
    }
}`

Comment: @y3z1 Could you try to explain a litte bit more. The button must be in pressed state, if the label is pressed.

Comment: Add **IsChecked** property in the custom Button class, then detect the value to set  **Control.Pressed** to true in custom renderer class.`public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsSelectedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsSelected), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomButton), null);
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        set => SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks for you help @y3z1 . You point me to the right direction!

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT could you please formulate your comment in an answer for users with a similar issue.

Comment: @Cfun Thanksfor your reminder, I've post an answer about the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i bind the label and the button so that the button indicates pressed state if i tap the label

To change the pressed state, try to achieve this feature on each platform. Create a custom Button and add a **bool** property such as 'IsChecked'. Then override the **OnElementPropertyChanged** in the custom renderer class, detect the value of the bool property to change the pressed state.For example:

Custom control class

```
public class CustomButton : Button 
{ 
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsSelectedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsSelected), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomButton), null); 
    public bool IsSelected 
    { 
        set => SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); 
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); 
    } 
}
```

Custom renderer class

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e); 
    var customButton = Element as CustomButton; 
    if (customButton.IsCheckeded) 
    { 
        Control.Pressed = true; 
    } 
}
```